# How to put the website in the read only mode?

Tags: 7

how to freeze the website so that any changes cannot be made by the user on the websites? I want to put the website on the read only mode . Read only mode module is there but is this possible through coding?

Comment: Yes, the readonly module (and readonlymode module) are both written in code; you can use the same approaches as they do in your own module

Answer (score 2):

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_alter().
 */
function MYMODULE_form_alter($form, $form_state, $form_id) {
  $form['#attributes'] = array('disabled' => TRUE);
  drupal_set_message("Website is currently in read only mode. During this it is not possible to change site content", "warning");
}
```

You can use above code in your custom module.